# Defining fields in Laravel 5.5 Migrations with Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, migration

Working with Laravel 5.5 Migrations with Postgres :

1) Defining field as :

```
$table->enum('is_applied', ['Y', 'N']) ->comment('Y => is_applied, N=> Is not applied');
```

I see in generated table next:

```
is_applied varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cs_tmp_csvps_is_applied_check CHECK (((is_applied)::text = ANY ((ARRAY['Y'::character varying, 'N'::character varying])::text[]))),
```

actually I would like to get sql I used in Postgres with type:

```
CREATE TYPE type_cms_item_content_type AS ENUM (
    'P',
    'M',
    'H'
);

    content_type type_cms_item_content_type NOT NULL DEFAULT 'P'::type_cms_item_content_type,
```

Is it possible?

2) Defining field as :

```
$table->timestamps();
```

I have 2 fields created created_at and  updated_at .
As I need to create only created_at I could write :

﻿

```
$table->dateTime('created_at');
```

But is there is a way to set default time on server, like :

```
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
```

for the timestamps issue. If you really want exact sql changes you can always do a raw sql statement in a migration:

```
Schema::table('content_type', function(Blueprint $table){
    $sql = 'CREATE TYPE type_cms_item_content_type AS ENUM (
    `P`,
    `M`,
    `H`
);

    content_type type_cms_item_content_type NOT NULL DEFAULT `P`::type_cms_item_content_type';
    DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Defining field as:

```
$table->enum('is_applied', ['Y', 'N']) ->comment('Y => is_applied, N=> Is not applied');
```

The method `comment()` it's only for MySQL, in the Migrations on Laravel.

See for more details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#creating-columns

2) Defining field as:

The Answer of @alex-harris is a gob option

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#column-modifiers  for more details

Comment: Thanks! I did not find if there is some option for updated_at, like useCurrent but updating?

Comment: @user2339232 see the issue in GitHub https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10005  You can modifie your Model.